# Count occurance of values within condition between column or rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which goes like this:-

```
2017-03-01  31.8  28.0     32.6
2017-04-01  31.6  28.0     32.6
2017-05-01  31.0  27.0     32.6
2017-06-01  31.0  27.0     32.4
2017-07-01  31.0  27.0     31.4
2017-08-01  30.0  27.0     32.6
```

Apart from first column, rest of column are temperature. What I would like to do is to compare the values of 4th column (last from right) with other column values to find if temperature values are not more or less than two deg (of 4th column). For example, I would like to count how many times all three columns (row wise) has the value between 30.6 to 34.6.

Is there a function available under pandas to do that?

Comment: what is your expected out put base on your example ?

Comment: Do you want to compare all three values in each row to [30.6 ... 34.6] or to whatever value is in the 4th column?

Comment: Whatever is there in the fourth column. I gave that specific example because it was there in the first row fourth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values of columns `a` `b` that is less than more than 2 of `c`

```
In [726]: (df[['a', 'b']].sub(df['c'], axis=0).abs() < 2).all(1).sum()
Out[726]: 0

In [727]: (df[['a', 'b']].sub(df['c'], axis=0).abs() < 2)
Out[727]:
       a      b
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3   True  False
4   True  False
5  False  False
```

Values between 30.6 to 34.6

```
In [671]: (df[['a', 'b', 'c']] > 30.6) & (df[['a', 'b', 'c']] < 34.6)
Out[671]:
       a      b     c
0   True  False  True
1   True  False  True
2   True  False  True
3   True  False  True
4   True  False  True
5  False  False  True
```

Values between 30.6 to 34.6, for all columns in a row to be True

```
In [672]: ((df[['a', 'b', 'c']] > 30.6) & (df[['a', 'b', 'c']] < 34.6)).all(1)
Out[672]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Count of rows where values are between 30.6 to 34.6 for all columns

```
In [673]: ((df[['a', 'b', 'c']] > 30.6) & (df[['a', 'b', 'c']] < 34.6)).all(1).sum()
Out[673]: 0
```

Comment: @sundar_ima Now. I am confused. You said you want to compare to the value in the last column, whatever it is; but in this solution, the fixed range of [30.6 .. 34.6] is used for all rows.  Is this what you really want?

Comment: FYI - That scenario was answered in the beginning.

Comment: @JohnGalt Ok, I was confused by the OP's reference to your _last_ example.

Answer (score 2):

Base on you sample data , you can try :

```
df2[['t1','t2','t3']].apply(lambda x : abs(x-df2['t3'])<2).sum(axis=1)==3

Out[425]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Data Input

```
    df2
    Out[426]: 
             Time    t1  t2    t3
    0  2017-03-01  31.8  28  32.6
    1  2017-04-01  31.6  28  32.6
    2  2017-05-01  31.0  27  32.6
    3  2017-06-01  31.0  27  32.4
    4  2017-07-01  31.0  27  31.4
    5  2017-08-01  30.0  27  32.6
```

Comment: The numbers 30.6, 32.6, and 34.6 are just examples for the first row of the table.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know how many times all of the values are withing the range ±2 of the fourth column (the columns are numbered 0,1,2,3):

```
(((df[3] - df[1]).abs() < 2) & ((df[3] - df[2]).abs() < 2)).sum()
#0
```

Comment: BTW , thank you for point out my misunderstanding ~ Thanks again +1

Comment: It gave me `KeyError: 3`. I did not see your answer before accepting John answer. You have understood my question exactly.

Comment: As I said, the columns in my example are numbered 0 through 3. You never said in your post what are the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dataframe.apply` to perform the comparison for each row, and sum the results of the comparison.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [31.8,  28.0,     32.6],
        [31.6,  28.0,     32.6],
        [31.0,  27.0,     32.6],
        [31.0,  27.0,     32.4],
        [31.0,  27.0,     31.4],
        [30.0,  27.0,     32.6]
    ],
    index=['2017-03-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-05-01', '2017-06-01', '2017-07-01', '2017-08-01']
)

df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum((x > 30.6) & (x < 34.6)), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0`, you'll get a count of the columns that meet your criteria

Comment: The numbers 30.6, 32.6, and 34.6 are just examples for the first row of the table.